# Hi I need one suggestion . If i click on one check box that containing some values .. That values are referering to other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi I need one suggestion . If i click on one check box that containing some values .. That values are referering to other checkboxes. If i click on first checkbox then related to  selected checkbox values same value checkboxes will be activated or other checkboxes will be deactivated.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sizecheck", function(event) {
  var value1 = $(this).attr('attrb');
  var value2 = value1.split(',');

  for (var i = 0; i < value2.length; i++) {
    $(".coloridchange").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('href') == value2[i]) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red!important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" attrb="1,2" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<input type="checkbox" attrb="4,5" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<br/> check box active state
<li class="coloridchange" href="1">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="1" id="item0" name="color">1</li>

<li class="coloridchange" href="2">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="2" id="item0" name="color">2</li>

<li class="coloridchange" href="4">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="4" id="item0" name="color">4</li>

<li class="coloridchange" href="5">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="5" id="item0" name="color">5</li>
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique. LI does not have  `href` property

Comment: use toggleClass instead of addClass

Comment: @Rajesh I aM JUsT GIVING EXAMPLE

Comment: @VinodLouis but i want all other li should be deactivated.... Like if i selected first checkbox and its value is 1,2  then 1,2 li only activated other should be deactivate

Comment: If you dont have solution please sir dont downvoted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

- On click, check if current checkbox is checked. If yes, set its value to `attrb` property. If not, set it to blank.
- Now loop over all `li`s and save `href`(*`data-id` in below example*) in a variable.
- Now use `.toggleClass('className', expression)` to *add/remove* class. `true` to add and `false` to remove.

**Sample:**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sizecheck", function(event) {
  var value1 = $(this).is(":checked")? $(this).attr('attrb') : "";
  $('li.coloridchange').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).data('id')
    $(this).toggleClass('active', value1.indexOf(href)>-1)
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red!important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" attrb="1,2" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<input type="checkbox" attrb="4,5" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<br/> check box active state
<li class="coloridchange" data-id="1">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="1" name="color">1</li>

<li class="coloridchange" data-id="2">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="2" name="color">2</li>

<li class="coloridchange" data-id="4">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="4" name="color">4</li>

<li class="coloridchange" data-id="5">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="5" name="color">5</li>
```

Comment: hi sir @Rajesh remaining checkboxes there is no inactive class ... how to add that

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd to use `href` attribute for this.  I'd recommend using custom attributes like `meta-href` or something that's memorable to you.  Next, I would recommend changing your `.each` with a selector search, it's cleaner.  I also added a `is(":checked")` to make sure we didn't just click to uncheck it.  Every time you click, it will wipe all with the `.removeClass` then it will highlight the correct elements.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sizecheck", function(event) {
  $(".coloridchange").removeClass('active');
  $(".sizecheck").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var values = $(this).attr('attrb').split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        $(".coloridchange[meta-href=\"" + values[i] + "\"]").addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red!important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" attrb="1,2" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<input type="checkbox" attrb="4,5" class="sizecheck" name="size">

<br/> check box active state
<li class="coloridchange" meta-href="1">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="1" id="item0" name="color">1</li>

<li class="coloridchange" meta-href="2">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="2" id="item0" name="color">2</li>

<li class="coloridchange" meta-href="4">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="4" id="item0" name="color">4</li>

<li class="coloridchange" meta-href="5">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="hidden" value="5" id="item0" name="color">5</li>
```